# WPF Charting with Dynamic Data Display: How can I show a regression line?

Tags: c#, charts, linear-regression, dynamic-data-display

I'm using [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) (D3) to render a few simple `LineSeries` on a chart:

```
<d3:ChartPlotter>
    <d3:CursorCoordinateGraph/>
    <d3:LineGraph DataSource="{Binding SelectedGraphValues}"/>
    <!-- ... Snip ...-->
</d3:ChartPlotter>
```

here is a small example graph:
[image: example chart]
* image from http://dynamicnotions.blogspot.com/2009/05/linear-regression-in-c.html

Is there a simple way to do this with D3? Or do I have to make the calculations myself? I just want to check before I reinvent the wheel here :-)

D3 is a very neat library, altough it's lacking a bit in documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and going through samples from DynamicDataDisplay, I guess it's not built in (could've been though, there's a lot of stuff in that library!)

So I just created a new `LineGraph` and a new `ObservableDataSource` to bind it to, and calculated the regression myself.